# iOS 11 Settings : check by code if 'In-App Ratings & Reviews' switch is on/off?

Tags: ios, ios11

Does someone know if there is a way by code to detect that the new switch
"In-App Ratings & Reviews"(*) in the settings of the device is off ? (* under "iTunes & App Stores")

Thank you very much for any response.

Comment: I don't believe so. The intention of the `SKStoreReviewController` is to abstract any work from the app in determining if the review request should be displayed, to avoid abuse. If they allowed the app to check the setting it would defeat the purpose since an app could just display its own alert if the setting was turned off.

Comment: "since an app could just display its own alert if the setting was turned off" : it will not be able to do that on September, Apple will reject any app that do that.                                                                                                                       https://dzone.com/articles/how-and-when-to-ask-for-reviews-including-ios-103"On iOS 10.3 and above, you will use the requestReview() method. It is important to note that you can not call this method in response to a button click. See the SKStoreReviewController class for details."

Comment: That's correct, what's the reason for checking the user's setting?

Comment: Because if the switch is turn off there is no reason to ask for [SKStoreReviewController requestReview], and we would like to do some analytics about user switching off...

Comment: All you have to do is call `requestReview` and the app will automatically decide to show it or not, taking into account the user's setting. But I don't think it would be possible for you to do the analytics.

Comment: Thank you Paolo for your responses

Comment: @Paolo Is there any update since then? Still, it is not possible to get it even in iOS 13x, 14?